# Store Arguments and Variables And Use With Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am re-writing the Write-Progress function to work better with my script and to accomplish this I am joining all the arguments into a string and then trying to use it on the command however it is not working.

Function

```
Function Update-Progress {
Param (
    [String] $Activity,
    [Bool] $Completed,
    [String] $CurrentOperation,
    [Int] $ID,
    [Int] $ParentID,
    [Int] $PercentComplete,
    [Int] $SecondsRemaining,
    [Int] $SourceID,
    [String] $Status
)
    If ($htDisplay.WriteProgress.Enable -EQ $True -AND $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 500) {
        $Parameters = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
        IF (isNull($Activity)) { Write-Error "Activity is Required" } Else { $Null = $Parameters.Append("-Activity `"$Activity`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($Completed))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -Completed")  }
        IF (!(isNull($CurrentOperation))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -CurrentOperation `"$CurrentOperation`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($ID))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -ID `"$ID`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($ParentID))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -ParentID `"$ParentID`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($PercentComplete))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -PercentComplete `"$PercentComplete`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($SecondsRemaining))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -SecondsRemaining `"$SecondsRemaining`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($SourceID))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append("-SourceID `"$SourceID`"")  }
        IF (!(isNull($Status))) { $Null = $Parameters.Append(" -Status `"$Status`"")  }
        "Write-Progress $Parameters"

        Write-Progress $Parameters

        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Reset()
        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Start()
    }
}
```

Command Calling Function

```
Update-Progress -ID 1 -Activity "Preloading threads" -Status "Starting Job $($htConfig.MultiThread.Jobs.count)"
```

Error - The Progress bar displays

```
-Activity "Preloading Threads" -ID "1" -Status "Starting Job #"
```

Write-Host of the exact command shows the following so the syntax is correct, just need to figure out how to process the variable as all the parameters instead of just the activity param.

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Preloading threads" -ID "1" -Status "Starting Job 2"
```

Answer (score 3):

> to accomplish this I am joining all the arguments into a string and then trying to use it on the command however it is not working.

That's a terrible idea - use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) with the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable instead - it already contains everything you need:

```
Function Update-Progress {
Param (
    [String] $Activity,
    [Bool] $Completed,
    [String] $CurrentOperation,
    [Int] $ID,
    [Int] $ParentID,
    [Int] $PercentComplete,
    [Int] $SecondsRemaining,
    [Int] $SourceID,
    [String] $Status
)
    If ($htDisplay.WriteProgress.Enable -EQ $True -AND $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 500) {

        Write-Progress @PSBoundParameters

        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Reset()
        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Start()
    }
}
```

I would probably go for a `Switch` rather than `Bool` for boolean parameters. You can grab the exact `Param` block from the original command with:

```
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($(Get-Command Write-Progress))
```

And end up with getting input validation and positional parameters corresponding to what `Write-Process` expects:

```
Function Update-Progress {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]${Activity},

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]${Status},

        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int]${Id},

        [ValidateRange(-1, 100)]
        [int]${PercentComplete},

        [int]${SecondsRemaining},

        [string]${CurrentOperation},

        [ValidateRange(-1, 2147483647)]
        [int]${ParentId},

        [switch]${Completed},

        [int]${SourceId}
    )

    If ($htDisplay.WriteProgress.Enable -EQ $True -AND $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 500) {

        Write-Progress @PSBoundParameters

        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Reset()
        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Start()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will def keep this in mind, however, I unfortunately am stuck using powershell v1.0 for this particular script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks to someone else here I have found the answer. It was inline expansion and I needed to use a hash table variable.

Source: [Inline expansion of powershell variable as cmdlet parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414763/inline-expansion-of-powershell-variable-as-cmdlet-parameter)

```
Function Update-Progress {
Param (
    [String] $Activity,
    [Bool] $Completed,
    [String] $CurrentOperation,
    [Int] $ID,
    [Int] $ParentID,
    [Int] $PercentComplete,
    [Int] $SecondsRemaining,
    [Int] $SourceID,
    [String] $Status
)
    If ($htDisplay.WriteProgress.Enable -EQ $True -AND $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -ge 500) {
        IF (isNull($Activity)) { Write-Error "Activity is Required" } Else { $Parameters = @{ Activity=$Activity }  }
        IF (!(isNull($Completed))) { $Parameters += @{ Completed=$Completed }  }
        IF (!(isNull($CurrentOperation))) { $Parameters += @{ CurrentOperation=$CurrentOperation }  }
        IF (!(isNull($ID))) { $Parameters += @{ ID=$ID}  }
        IF (!(isNull($ParentID))) { $Parameters += @{ ParentID=$ParentID }  }
        IF (!(isNull($PercentComplete))) { $Parameters += @{ PercentComplete=$PercentComplete }  }
        IF (!(isNull($SecondsRemaining))) { $Parameters += @{ SecondsRemaining=$SecondsRemaining }  }
        IF (!(isNull($SourceID))) { $Parameters += @{ SourceID=$SourceID }  }
        IF (!(isNull($Status))) { $Parameters += @{ Status=$Status }  }
        Write-Progress @Parameters
        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Reset()
        $htDisplay.WriteProgress.StopWatch.Start()
    }
}
```